# What are these red X's on packages and files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

What is causing these red X's on my files? I accidentally moved my source folder into another folder in my project and when I moved the folder back and recorrected the location of the source folder I started seeing red X's on all my files in that folder. My project builds and runs fine, but svn seems to still believe I have deleted all these files if I try to commit. Is subclipse marking them? I do not see any errors under problems and cannot figure out how remove these.

[image: Red X's]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means files are deleted and you need to commit the folder/package that's being deleted to reflect the same in the repository.

Comment: If I commit when they are considered deleted won't they be removed from the repository?

Comment: Yes you are right. They will be removed from repository.